# Transport vs Continuity equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, terminology, fluid-dynamics, transport-equation

For a time dependent vector field $v:\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$, and a say a (time dependent) probability density $u$, why do people call

$$ \partial_tu=\text{div }(uv), $$
the continuity equation, and

$$ \partial_t u=v\cdot \nabla u,  $$
the transport equation?

Surely the terminology distinguishes between two fundamentally different dynamics can anyone broadly explain the main difference?

Comment: The equation $\partial_t u=\text{div }(u\otimes v)$ usually appears in the formular of Euler equations; we can see it at the introduction of several papers. However, when we are going deeply into research, we will find that the form $\partial_tu=v\cdot\nabla u$ is more convenient to use.

Comment: On the other hand, $\partial_t u=\text{div }(u\otimes v)$ derives from some physical assumptions, so it has a name 'the continuity equation' due to physists; however, mathematicans found that the form $\partial_tu=v\cdot\nabla u$ is more convenient to use, which has a 'transport' feature. Also, when we call it 'a transport equation', it means that we will use some knowledge about transpot equations, which will help the readers to understand.

Comment: @Feng but its not just a matter of notation... if $v$ depends on space then it is affected by the divergence in the first, i.e. then these two things are not the same.

Comment: In some cases, the fluid is incompressible, hence $\text{div }v=0$, and thus this two equations are equivalent. If you want to consider a general case, they are different. The first equation is named by physicists and the second equation is a transport equation. You may refer to Evans the definition of transport equations.